# In webtoon image, want to save only the part of the image where there are people. So I make some code using

Tags: python-3.x, image, detection

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
`your text`
# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('your_image.jpg')

# Convert BGR to HSV color space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define the range of skin color in HSV
lower_skin = np.array([0, 48, 80], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_skin = np.array([20, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

# Threshold the HSV image to get only skin color
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_skin, upper_skin)

# Find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Save regions where skin color (people) is detected
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    person_region = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cv2.imwrite(f'person_{i}.jpg', person_region)
```

But the result get just one or two pixels only.

How can I get people(whole body) image in webtoon.

Before I used deep learning model like yolo or opencv. But it is not good at all.

Comment: Does this help if you move `cv2.imwrite` outside of looping?